# Accessibility settings asking everytime

Tags: macos, accessibility

Those two apps are always asking for the accessibility permission, one is location and the other is contacts. As the picture shows that I have *already* enabled those settings for them. It keep asking me every time I quit the app or on system startup when it run because of login items. Is there anyway to make it not ask again? or make the settings permanent.

OS : MacOS Sierra (10.12)

[image]

> The location permission for the Forecast bar is already granted, but whenever the app started, I found out that the location setting has been *unticked*, by itself.

[image]

Comment: Did you get any solution, same problem here I havent found workaround yet.

Comment: Sadly no. @PujanSrivastava I still have to grant access every time I reboot my mac.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by resetting app permissions with `tccutil` https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/344086

First, you need to find the bundle ID of your app via Terminal:
`mdls /Applications/Forecast\ Bar.app | grep kMDItemCF` (note that folder of your app may be different)

Then run `tccutil` to reset permissions:
`tccutil reset All [bundle ID]`

Application will ask for permissions once more, but now it will be saved correctly