# Reset All Mojave App Permissions

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, permission, mojave

So I upgraded to Mojave recently and I got some app permission popups requesting access to system events, etc.

I didn't recognise some of these the apps and didn't allow access.

Now it turns out that this is being used by xcodebuild and it is failing.

How can I reset all these app permissions. So that I get the popup again and I can allow this time.

PS: I'm not asking about file permissions.

Answer (score 22):

Some categories, like the one you mention, aren't listed in System Preferences.

You can reset that one in particular with this command:

```
tccutil reset AppleEvents
```

Or, you can reset **all** app permissions like this:

```
 tccutil reset All
```

You can also add an app's bundle identifier (e.g. `tccutil reset All com.apple.Terminal`) to reset only that app's permissions.

Comment: note that you can get the bundle id with `mdls /Applications/iPhoto.app | grep kMDItemCF`

Comment: … noting also that macOs installed applications are now mostly found under `/System/Applications`, e.g. `mdls /System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app | grep kMDItemCF`

Comment: `tccutil reset All`  NOTE: macOS Monterey -- If your computer freezes be patient.  Open Activity Monitor and Kill the WindowsServer Process, wait for it kick you out and re-login.  This should fix the issue.  *might just be my computer, just wanted to share.

Answer (score 5):

`man tccutil`

> The tccutil command manages the privacy database, which stores
>   decisions
>        the user has made about whether apps may access personal data.
>
> One command is current supported:
>
> ```
>  reset    Reset all decisions for the specified service, causing apps to
>           prompt again the next time they access the service. If a bundle
>           identifier is specified, the service will be reset for that bun-
>           dle only.
> ```
>
> EXAMPLES
>        To reset all decisions about whether apps may access the address book:
>
> ```
> tccutil reset AddressBook
> tccutil reset All com.apple.Terminal
> ```

Answer (score 3):

From the blog post ["Reauthorizing Automation in Mojave"](https://bitsplitting.org/2018/07/11/reauthorizing-automation-in-mojave/):

> If the user selects “OK”, the application sending the command will be
>   thereafter whitelisted, and allowed to send arbitrary events (not just
>   the one that prompted the alert) to the Finder. If you’re running
>   macOS Mojave you can see a list of applications you’ve already
>   permitted in System Preferences, under “Security and Privacy,”
>   “Privacy,” “Automation”.

Answer (score 2):

Theres also a nifty [tccutil replacement on github](https://github.com/jacobsalmela/tccutil) which is also available via [brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tccutil).

Comment: This util does not work in MacOS High Sierra and above because of SIP. Refer issue here https://github.com/jacobsalmela/tccutil/issues/18

Answer (score 0):

## The answer for macOS 14.0 Sonoma

Conditions that need to be met:

I believe SIP has to be disabled before you can `tccutil reset All`?

- `sudo shutdown -h now`
- startup into Recovery Mode and open Terminal.app
- `csrutil disable` `sudo shutdown -r now`

A user has to be root - enable root first:

- `dsenableroot` and enter a password
- `su root`
- `/usr/bin/tccutil reset All`

```
sh-3.2#  whoami
root
sh-3.2# /usr/bin/tccutil reset All
Successfully reset All
```

### caveats:

There is a [homebrew binary with the same name, `tccutil`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tccutil), that doesn't perform the same functions. Be aware if you have homebrew binaries first in your path:

```
sh-3.2# which -a tccutil
/usr/local/bin/tccutil
/usr/bin/tccutil
```