# How to turn off "terminal would like to administer your computer" message?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, administrator

I keep getting a warning message that terminal would like to administer my computer whenever I run standard commands, such as editing crontab in Vim. This never used to happen on my old Macbook. How do I turn off this feature?

Answer (score 8):

You need to give Terminal 'Full Disk Access" in System Preferences > Security & Privacy.

Choose **Full Disk Access** in the sidebar, and then unlock the padlock and enter an admin password. Then click the **+** button and add the Terminal application.

Comment: This requires running the GUI and a lot of clicking around on every machine. Is there no way to do this with a `sudo` command through ssh?

Comment: There might be ways to alter the TCC database on the command line, though it's undocumented. I imagine there are security reasons against letting remote processes increase their own access privileges.

Answer (score 4):

Please also see [Reset All Mojave App Permissions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342710/reset-all-mojave-app-permissions)

These are new(ish) security features that have been gradually introduced in recent macOS versions.  Apple noticeable ramped up these security controls with the release of mojave.

The system noticed that Terminal was being used to access files that aren't normally edited by end users.  (Were you attempting to edit the crontab for the root user? ... i.e. `sudo crontab -e`?

The command line utility that can control this is `tccutil`.

To reset warnings associated with the Terminal app, you can use `tccutil reset All com.apple.Terminal`.  This will reset permissions and warnings associated with Terminal back to factory defaults ... but from here you would be allowed to grant permissions to Terminal.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Resetting will put things back to the default.  The question is how to make, by default, macOS not to ask about this permission.