# Reset/Remove all entries in Security&Privacy>Privacy

Tags: catalina, privacy

How can I reset (which means remove) all entries in the System Settings > Security&Privacy > Privacy list?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342710/reset-all-mojave-app-permissions?noredirect=1&lq=1 Found it!